# How to electronically make a song follow a metronome?

Tags: sound-effects, song

I know very little about sound engineering so forgive my ignorance.

I was wondering if it is possible, with some free software, to take a song that hasn't been recorded with metronome (id est, its beats are non-homogeneously separated throughout the song) and make it follow a constant beat (in order to add a kick or whatever electronic base to it)?

Answer (score 2):

Modern DAW software often includes a feature to build a 'Tempo Map' of recorded audio tracks (your own recorded material or audio imported into the project from elsewhere).

A Tempo Map follows the ebb and flow of the tempo in recorded material, and builds a grid around it so that you can then use features such as 'Snap to Grid' and 'Quantize' to fit your MIDI data to the song.

This means the original recorded material stays the same, but you can fit your electronic beat to match the rhythm/tempo of the song.

If you search 'Tempo Map' in Google, you'll see various tutorials on how to do this, depending on your DAW of choice.

Comment: +1. Always remember that time stretching is very complicated and program dependent, and that this processing will lead to some (possibly very unpleasant) artifacts.